# pattern validator accept everything without word characters

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

i am trying to create a pattern that accept everything without word characters (a-z or A-Z) in angular.

```
  phone: new FormControl(null, [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern("^-?[0-9]\\d*(\\.\\d{1,2})?$"),
  ]),
```

i try this patter but not work fine because my goal is:

pattern must accept :

```
()*#%&#@64582 (example 1)
3796592#$#@$%^&$&/ (exapmle 2)
34242+5334?@^#$#%4242 (example 3)
```

That mean everything without (a-z or A-Z)

Pattern must not accept  :

```
$%$@#423URVB 
t3653$^%#&#%&
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Use a negated character class instead ...?

Comment: [^A-Za-z] use this

Comment: in general: allow everything with out characters  like (abcdefg....).

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested pattern allows positive or negative floats and is not relevant to your wishes

Normally we use a negated class

```
/^[^a-zA-Z]$/g
```

but that will allow öää for example

```
/^[^a-zA-Z\p{L}]$/gu
```

will also block unicode characters but allow special characters

https://regex101.com/r/WxARn2/1

I can however not find how to add the flag to Angular PatternValidator so you will need to test it

Comment: Validators.pattern("[^a-zA-Zp{L}]") like this in angular.? @mplungjan

Comment: I am not sure. I cannot find the /u parameter in the Angular documentation